# Save billing address to custom checkout field if empty in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have followed a tutorial on how to include custom fields at checkout in woocommerce, everything works, as expected but I want to save the full billing address to this custom field if is not filled.

This is what I have

```
function cloudways_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
// don't forget appropriate sanitization if you are using a different field type
if( isset( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cloudways_text_field', sanitize_text_field( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) );

if(empty($posted['cloudways_text_field']))
    {
    // it's empty!
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cloudways_text_field', sanitize_text_field( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) );
    }
else
    {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cloudways_text_field', sanitize_text_field( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) );
    }    

}
```

}
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',      'cloudways_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );

But I don't know how to save the array of billing address to this custom text field if it's not filled.

Link to tutorial is https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-edit-delete-fields-and-email-in-woocommerce-custom-checkout-fields/amp/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try building the address into an array and saving that in the field. Or you can also build it to a string, really depends what data you want the field to contain, string or array.
Here is an example of an array:

```
function cloudways_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ) {
    // don't forget appropriate sanitization if you are using a different field type
    if ( isset( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cloudways_text_field', sanitize_text_field( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) );

        if ( empty( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) ) {
            $billing_address_array = array(
                'billing_address_1' => $posted['billing_address_1'],
                'billing_address_2' => $posted['billing_address_2'],
                'billing_city'      => $posted['billing_city'],
                'billing_postcode'  => $posted['billing_postcode'],
                'billing_state'     => $posted['billing_state'],
                'billing_country'   => $posted['billing_country'],
            );
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cloudways_text_field', wc_clean( $billing_address_array ) );
        } else {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_cloudways_text_field', sanitize_text_field( $posted['cloudways_text_field'] ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'cloudways_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: it worked perfect, since I needed just plain text I just modified the wc_clean part to:  implode(" ", $billing_address_array ) );    Thanks so much

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Foxtrail815 , it would be nice if the answer was useful to you, accept it as such, marking the "V" sign as you can [see in the screenshot](https://ibb.co/SVMBp1N) , and thus help other users with your same problem. Thank you